# SSIS Setting OLE_DB Connection string from variable is not working getting error code dts_e_cannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager

Tags: ssis, connection-string

I have a parent child package situation where the parent is reading a SQL Server task table. Loops through the tasks and gets the connection string needed for the the task and passes it to the child package. I have created and set a variable in the parent package. I have also created and set a variable n the child package in a Script Task. The Variable is set to the Connection String of my OLE_DB connection in an expression (Package.DelayValidation = True). After the Script task runs(and works..I displayed a message box with the correct value) I run a Data Flow Task which trys to read the database using the connection string. This is where the "error code dts_e_cannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager" happens. I know I have to be missing something, just can not put my finger on it.
[image: Child Package Flow]
[image: Script Task Code]
[image: Variable Usage]

Answer (score 0):

Since both packages are available in a single project, try to select `Project Reference` ,in the parent package, as the `ReferenceType` and in the `PackageNameFromProjectReference` enter your child  .

Comment: I checked ReferenceType and it was already set to Project Reference. And the ConnectionString data is making it to the Child project. It is just not making it into the SQL Connection of the Connection Manager for some reason.